# Marking primitive types with phantom types in Scala

Tags: scala, types, static-analysis

In Scala I can use the concept of phantom types (as described e.g. [here](http://blog.rafaelferreira.net/2008/07/type-safe-builder-pattern-in-scala.html)) to mark types and have this information erased at runtime. I wonder whether it is possible to mark primitive types with phantom types without having them boxed.

An example could be a function that lets an Int only pass if it is a prime. The signature might look similar to the following:

```
def filterPrime(i: Int): Option[Int with IsPrime]
```

The function returns the value `Some(i)` if `i` is prime or `None` else.

Is the stated idea possible to implement in Scala without boxing the primitive integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
trait IsPrime
val x = 5.asInstanceOf[Int with IsPrime]
val y:Int = x

val z:Int with IsPrime = 6 /* this line causes a compile error
                              which is what you want */
```

Comment: Interesting. I don't quite understand why the cast works despite `Int` beeing `final`. I would consider this more a bug than a feature.

Comment: @Landei: I'm not sure either. That would be a good question to ask on one of the scala mailing lists, where one of the language designers could answer you.

Comment: @Landei Casts means "I know what I'm doing, don't try to correct me." You might get a run time error if it turns out you didn't know what you were doing, but not a compile time error.

Comment: I'll accept this as answer if you reconsider your last line in the light of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Building on Kim Stebel's answer I've compiled the following

```
trait IsOdd

object Test{
    def testOddity(i: Int): Int with IsOdd = 
        if( i % 2 == 0) throw new RuntimeException
        else i.asInstanceOf[Int with IsOdd]

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(testOddity(1))
    }
}
```

and invoked javap on the class `Test` with the following result

```
Compiled from "Test.scala"
public final class Test extends java.lang.Object{
public static final void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #11; //Field Test$.MODULE$:LTest$;
   3:   aload_0
   4:   invokevirtual   #13; //Method Test$.main:([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   7:   return

public static final int testOddity(int);
  Code:
   0:   getstatic   #11; //Field Test$.MODULE$:LTest$;
   3:   iload_0
   4:   invokevirtual   #17; //Method Test$.testOddity:(I)I
   7:   ireturn

}
```

We notice, that the function `testOddity` has been compiled to return an unboxed integer.

And the following file doesn't compile (which is also what we wanted).

```
trait IsOdd

object Test{
    def testOddity(i: Int): Int with IsOdd = 
        if( i % 2 == 0) throw new RuntimeException
        else i.asInstanceOf[Int with IsOdd]

    def acceptOdd(i: Int with IsOdd) { println("got it") }  
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(testOddity(1))
        acceptOdd(1)
    }
}
```

### compiler error

```
Test.scala:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Int with IsOdd
        acceptOdd(1)
                      ^
```