# Escape analysis in the .NET CLR VM

Tags: c#, optimization, clr, jit, escape-analysis

Is there any escape analysis performed by the CLR compiler/JIT?  For example, in Java it appears that <strike>a loop variable</strike> an object allocated in a loop that doesn't escape the loop gets allocated on the stack rather than the heap (see [Escape analysis in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771430/escape-analysis-in-java)).

To clarify, in the example below, would the compiler optimise away the heap allocation of `foo` as it never escapes the loop.

```
class Foo 
{ 
   int number;
   Foo(int number) { this.number = number; }
   public override string ToString() { return number.ToString(); }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
   Foo foo = new Foo(i);
   Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Typically, a loop variable is a value type, which gets allocated on the stack (in the case of a loop).

Comment: I mean a variable allocated within the loop body.  I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: Do you mean the *variable*? or the *object*? (conceptually very different)

Comment: Your `ToString()` is incorrect; that should be `public override ToString()` - emphasis on the `override`.

Comment: Yes, I did mean the object, not the variable.  I thought the reference to the Java version of the question would infer that, but I should have used the correct terms.  You are, as always, correct on the `ToString()`, I'll fix the code...

Comment: According to [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2999#issuecomment-560415677) from December 2nd 2019: _"...escape analysis and stack allocation which is currently being worked on by the runtime team"_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you mean the *object* ( `new Foo(i);` ), then my understanding is that no: this is never allocated on the stack; however, it will die in generation zero, so will be very efficient to collect. I don't profess to know every dark and dank corner of the CLI, but I am not aware of any scenario **in C#** that would lead to a managed reference-type being allocated on the stack (things like `stackalloc` don't really count, and are highly specific). Obviously in C++ you have a few more options, but then it isn't a managed instance.

Interestingly, on MonoTouch/AOT it *might* be collected immediately, but that is not the main CLI VM (and is for a very specific scenario).

As for the *variable* - that *will* usually be on the stack (and re-used for each loop iteration) - but it **might not be**. For example, if this is an "iterator block", then all the non-removed local-variables are actually fields on the compiler-generated state-machine. More commonly, if the variable is "captured" (into an anonymous method or lambda expression, both of which form closures), then the variable is transformed into a field on the compiler-generated capture-context, **and** is separate per loop iteration (since `foo` is declared inside the loop). This means that each is *separate* on the heap.

As for `i` (the loop variable) - if *that* gets captured, it gets even more interesting

- in C# 1.2 captures didn't exist, but by the spec the loop-variable is *technically* per-iteration
- in C# 2.0 to 4.0, the loop variable is shared (causing the infamous capture/foreach common question)
- in C# 5.0 and above the loop variable is per-iteration again

this only makes a difference when the variable is captured, but changes the semantics of exactly *how* it manifests on the capture-context

Answer (score 7):

A value type might be allocated on the stack (not always), but the same is not true for instances of reference types. In fact:

> In particular, the storage locations of instances of reference types are always treated as though they are long-lived, even if they are provably short-lived. Therefore they always go on the heap.

(Eric Lippert: [The Truth About Value Types](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types.aspx))

Also [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) makes a good reading.

Answer (score 1):

While the x86 JIT is good at 'inlining' valuetypes, your snippet will not qualify as the `ToString` method will be a virtual call on a boxed object. **Edit:** This may not be the case, as you are not overriding `ToString`.

The x64 JIT however does not do this at all from my experiments.

**Edit:**

If possible, test your code on both x86 and x64.

Comment: `Foo` is a class though, so I'm not sure how much of this applies.